# How to return names of events scheduled on the same date at the same location as 'JOHN BIRTHDAY'

Tags: oracle

I got this question in the exam wrong, and I want to know how to fix it? How to return names of events scheduled on the same date at the same location as 'JOHN BIRTHDAY'?

```
Select ename from event e1, location L where  e1.LID=L.LID AND  

 E1.ENAME='JOHN BIRTHDAY' AND E1.START_DATE=DATE'2017-01-02';
```

EVENT TABLE: LID= LOCATION ID , AND MID = MEMBER ID

```
EID ENAME           MID  LID START_DAT  END_DATE
1   JOHN BIRTHDAY    1  2   02-JAN-17   02-JAN-17
2   SAMI BIRTHDAY    2  1   02-JAN-17   02-JAN-17
4   THANKSGIVING     2  2   02-JAN-17   02-JAN-17
3   SUSAN GRADUATION 1  2   02-JAN-17   02-JAN-17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did wrong...

You are looking up data in two tables, EVENT and LOCATION. You match them by LOCATION_ID - no harm there. But then, from EVENT you select just one row: the row where ENAME = 'JOHN BIRTHDAY'. Then the first mistake: to that, you add "and START_DATE - ..."  No need for that; you already limited the rows from the EVENT table to the row with ENAME = 'JOHN BIRTHDAY'.

Then: you are joining to LOCATION for absolutely no reason; you are not selecting anything from LOCATION. (Nor do you need to, since the problem is asking you to find other events that share the same location, meaning the same LOCATION_ID, and that is already available in the EVENT table.)

The biggest mistake: nowhere in your code are you looking for OTHER events. With some constraints: same date and location as 'JOHN BIRTHDAY', but that is irrelevant since you are not looking for ANY other events, anywhere in the code.

How to solve this problem correctly:

You need to look up data in EVENT twice. One time to find out when and where 'JOHN BIRTHDAY' will be. (It is not stated in the problem, but the convention during an exam is that you are not supposed to read the date and location in the table, write them down, and then hard-code them in your query; instead, they should be "variables" in the solution.) Second time you need to look IN THE SAME TABLE to find other events with the same date and location.

So this means you will need to join EVENT to itself (give it two different aliases, so you can refer to them clearly - "this" copy vs. "that" copy of the table). Join them by LID and ... date ... but that's more complicated (see below). Select the ENAME from one copy, while in the other copy put the WHERE condition: where ENAME = 'JOHN BIRTHDAY'.

Something like

```
select e1.ename
from   event e1 join event e2 on e1.lid = e2.lid and e1.start_date = e2.start_date
where  e2.ename = 'JOHN BIRTHDAY'
;
```

**which is what Darzen posted in a different Answer before I typed mine.**

This may be all you need, except for the following interesting question. The base data has a START_DATE and an END_DATE, not just a straight DATE. Does that mean that an event may be from 9 AM to noon, while 'JOHN BIRTHDAY' is from 6 PM to 8:30 PM? Or perhaps, does it mean that some events may extend for two or three days, and you need to find all those that **overlap** with 'JOHN BIRTHDAY'?

That makes the problem more interesting, but let's leave it alone; what I shared with you so far may suffice.

Final note - you may be better off learning modern (SQL Standard) notation for joins. You used Oracle syntax, which is not wrong, but it is not the best option.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.ename 
from events a , 
     (select ename, lid, start_Date from events)  b 
where a.lid = b.lid and a.start_date = b.start_date
      and a.ename = 'JOHN BIRTHDAY' and b.ename <> 'JOHN BIRTHDAY';
```

Comment: Why do you want to exclude 'JOHN BIRTHDAY' from the output? Surely it is held in the same location and at the same time as itself!

Comment: Sure.. In that case it would be just
select b.ename 
from events a , 
     (select ename, lid, start_Date from events)  b 
where a.lid = b.lid and a.start_date = b.start_date
      and a.ename = 'JOHN BIRTHDAY';

Comment: In addition, if you have that condition, and if ENAME may be NULL (we don't know, perhaps that is allowed in the table), you will miss those; if you keep that condition, you may want to add null handling so they are not missed.

Comment: Whether we want to include 'JOHN BIRTHDAY' or not, don't we need to add null handling either ways?

Comment: No, because the join is on LID and START_DATE (and we assume those are not NULL - or if they may be, they will not match 'JOHN BIRTHDAY' anyway). But an unnamed event *may* be reserved for the same (non-NULL) location and date. As long as the LID and START_DATE match, the ENAME will not be missed even if it is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like

```
WITH cteJOHN_BIRTHDAY AS (SELECT *
                            FROM EVENT
                            WHERE ENAME = 'JOHN BIRTHDAY')
SELECT e.ENAME
  FROM EVENT e
  INNER JOIN cteJOHN_BIRTHDAY j
    ON j.START_DAT = e.START_DAT AND
       j.LID = e.LID AND
       j.EID <> e.EID
```

ought to do it.

Not tested on animals - you'll be first! :-)